# ADODB Recordset Object may have empty fields values but the query result does have all the values

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, adodb

I try to store some data I get from the DataBase in a ADODB.Connection Object so I can use that object later in the program. The problem is that recently the object have some fields with the value of "nothing" but the query that is used have all the fields filled.

I have a function that retrieves the information I need and then I asign the result to an object I use later.

```
Dim recordSet As Object

recordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

recordSet = functionThatReturnsAObject()

'Later I access to the values of the object
```

When I use:

```
recordSet.GetRows()
```

Some values of the array returns Nothing.

But if I do:

```
functionThatReturnsAObject().GetRows
```

It returns all the fields with it's values.

The function I use is something like this:

```
Private Function functionThatReturnsAObject() As Object    
  Dim anotherRecordSet As Object = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
  Dim sqlCommand As Object = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Dim bdConnection As Object = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

  bdConnection.Open(GlobalVar)
  sqlCommand.ActiveConnection = bdConnection
  sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT 'HERE_GOES_THE_QUERY'"

  sqlCommand.CommandType = 1
  sqlCommand.Prepared = True
  With sqlCommand.Parameters
    .Append(sqlCommand.CreateParameter("param", 200, 1, 10, value))
    'More parameters come here
  End With
  anotherRecordSet = sqlCommand.Execute

  Return anotherRecordSet 
End Function
```

I'm not sure if it's related with the number of columns that have the query (more than 70). But the problem comes when I try to assign the value that return the fuction to the Object I need to use later. Or maybe it is because I use .Execute instead of .Open?

Comment: Since this is SQL Server why not use ADO.net with the SQL Server Provider?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment.
I could try that, but I wanted to know why when I assign the value of the function some data get lost somewhere. Because if I don't know why that happens it means I have to change all the places where I create an object and I assign it a value from a function; because it may lose some data.
I should edit my question, some fields, not all of them, have "Nothing" as a value when they should have a value. But sometimes the same fields can have a value with the very same query. Also the object the function returns have all the values.